# How to expand environment variable inside string read from file?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I have a file with a list of paths. Some of them might include environment variables such as `%USERPROFILE%`.

Example:

```
%USERPROFILE%\dir
C:\another\dir
```

I'm then reading all the lines and concatenating with `;` using this code (the cat and tr commands are available because of git):

```
set include_file=C:\path\to\file.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cat %include_file% ^| tr "\\n" ";"') do set include_content=%%i
```

This creates a variable with the string `%USERPROFILE%\dir;C:\another\dir`
Normally running `echo %USERPROFILE%` would give you something like `C:\Users\xxx\dir` but running it with `%include_content%` just outputs the original string without expanding `%USERPATH%`

My final plan is to add the directories to my PATH like this `set PATH=%include_content%;%PATH%` but this doesn't work since the variable isn't expanded.

My question is can I somehow expand the variables in the string so that the real directories get added to the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reparse a line by using `CALL`.

So this should do the job

```
call set "include_content=%include_content%"
```

After the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Buliding on jeb's answer, you may wish to prevent the same directory from being added to `%PATH%` multiple times.  To do this, loop through each directory both in `%PATH%` and in `%include_content%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set include_file=test.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cat %include_file% ^| tr "\n" ";"') do set "include_content=%%i"

call set "include_content=%include_content%"

for %%I in ("%include_content:;=" "%") do if exist "%%~I" (
    set found=
    for %%J in ("%PATH:;=" "%") do (
        if /I "%%~I"=="%%~J" set found=1
    )
    if not defined found set "PATH=!PATH!;%%~I"
)

:: uncomment to make permanent
rem setX PATH %PATH%
echo %PATH%
```

Comment: Very useful to avoid problems with the path variable