# Batch - Echoing file without expanding the variables inside the file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, variables, for-loop

This is probably the exact opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115337/how-to-expand-environment-variable-inside-string-read-from-file).

Anyways, I have a batch file with such content:

<kbd>a.bat</kbd>

```
@echo %random%
```

And I tries to read the <kbd>a.bat</kbd> through another batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir *.bat') do (
    rem loop through files
    for /f "delims=" %%q in ('type %%~p') do echo %%q 
) 2>nul
```

And it outputs:

> `@echo (random number)`

How can I make it outputs `@echo %random%`? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are testing,  but your described result can't be the output of your code

Comment: Weird. On my Win7 it outputs `@echo (the random number)`

Comment: Is it always the same number? What is the real content of x.bat?

Comment: The number isn't always same as it is `%random%`. The real content would be too long to fit here, but anyways I used another workaround and removed the old script `:(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works here (win 8). Only added the `/B` switch to dir command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /B a.bat') do (
    rem loop through files
    for /f "delims=" %%q in ('type %%~p') do echo %%q 
) 2>nul
```

But you can also try

```
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /B a.bat') do (
  for /F "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%1 in ('"type "%%~p"|find /N /V """') do echo/%%2
)
EndLocal
```

In my computer both give `@echo %ramdon%`

Comment: Typo in the last sentence... By the way, the second solution works like a charm :)

Comment: It fails, when a line starts with `[`, `]` or `?`. See also [SO:How to read a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531090/463115)